# What is the fastest way to test if a double number is integer (in modern intel X86 processors)

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, x86, sse

Our server application does a lot of integer tests in a hot code path, currently we use the following function:

```
inline int IsInteger(double n)
{
    return n-floor(n) < 1e-8
}
```

This function is very hot in our workload, so I want it to be as fast as possible. I also want to eliminate the "floor" library call if I can. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't n - floor(n) be exactly 0 if n is an integer? Are you working with very large integers that might exceed the precision of a double?

Comment: `floor` should typically be implemented as intrinsic, meaning there is no actual function call in the output. You should check the optimized assembly output to be sure.

Comment: do you mean Integer (as in no fractional part) or do you mean int (as in a value between MAX_INT and MIN_INT)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share the compiler output with us.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of problem domain requires such tests? I would have expected that you would need `round` rather than `floor`. E.g. `fabs(n-round(n)) < 1e-8`. Otherwise you could try using the `modf` function.

Comment: You say it is very hot in your workload. I assume that is based on proof by profiling, and that you have done all other possible optimizations. Many times people concentrate on low-level optimizations when in fact there are bigger issues that are easier to fix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A while back [I ran a bunch of timings on the most efficient way to convert between floats and integers, and wrote them up](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/why-you-should-never-cast-floats-to-ints/). I also [timed techniques for rounding](http://assemblyrequired.crashworks.org/sse2-fastest-rounding-on-x86/).

The short story for you is: converting from a float to an int, or using union hacks, is unlikely to be an improvement due to a CPU hazard called a load-hit-store -- *unless* the floats are coming from RAM and not a register.

Because it is an intrinsic, abs(floor(x)-eps) is probably the fastest solution. But because this is all very sensitive to the particular architecture of your CPU -- depending on very sensitive things like pipeline depth and store forwarding -- *you'll need to time a variety of solutions* to find one that is really optimal.

Comment: Thank you. But again I emphasize: you need to precisely time the solutions you are considering with your particular compiler and CPU. This sort of microoptimzation is extremely sensitive to the quirks of a particular CPU stepping's internal design.

Answer (score 11):

Here are a couple of answers:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int IsInteger1(double n)
{
  union
  {
        uint64_t i;
        double d;
  } u;
  u.d = n;

  int exponent = ((u.i >> 52) & 0x7FF) - 1023;
  uint64_t mantissa = (u.i & 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFFllu);

  return n == 0.0 ||
        exponent >= 52 ||
        (exponent >= 0 && (mantissa << (12 + exponent)) == 0);
}

int IsInteger2(double n)
{
  return n - (double)(int)n == 0.0;
}

int IsInteger3(double n)
{
  return n - floor(n) == 0.0;
}
```

And a test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int IsInteger1(double);
int IsInteger2(double);
int IsInteger3(double);

#define TIMEIT(expr, N) \
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL); \
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++) \
  { \
    expr; \
  } \
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL); \
  printf("%s: %f\n", #expr, (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + 0.000001 * (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const int N = 100000000;
  struct timeval start, end;
  int i;

  double d = strtod(argv[1], NULL);
  printf("d=%lf %d %d %d\n", d, IsInteger(d), IsInteger2(d), IsInteger3(d));

  TIMEIT((void)0, N);
  TIMEIT(IsInteger1(d), N);
  TIMEIT(IsInteger2(d), N);
  TIMEIT(IsInteger3(d), N);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile as:

```
gcc isinteger.c -O3 -c -o isinteger.o
gcc main.c isinteger.o -o isinteger
```

My results, on an Intel Core Duo:

```
$ ./isinteger 12345
d=12345.000000 1 1 1
(void)0: 0.357215
IsInteger1(d): 2.017716
IsInteger2(d): 1.158590
IsInteger3(d): 2.746216
```

Conclusion: the bit twiddling isn't as fast as I might have guessed.  The extra branches are probably what kills it, even though it avoids floating-point operations.  FPUs are fast enough these days that doing a `double`-to-`int` conversion or a `floor` really isn't that slow.

Comment: Glory be, hard numbers! Any reason why you didn't just write the test in `IsInteger2` as `n == (double)(int)n`?

Comment: We do not test for "exactly equal to integer number". A number with fraction part small enough is recognized as integer number in our application, such as "1.000000001".

Comment: In gcc 4.5.0 (20090912), -O2 and -O3 both optimize away the floor call, apparently.

Comment: I carefully checked again and neither -O3 nor -O3 optmized away the "floor" call, I'm using gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1).

Answer (score 4):

If `double`s on your machine are IEEE-754 compliant, this union describes the double's layout.

```
union
{
   double d;
   struct
   {
       int sign     :1
       int exponent :11
       int mantissa :52
   };
} double_breakdown;
```

This will tell you if the double represents an integer.

Disclaimer 1: I'm saying **integer**, and not **`int`**, as a double can represent numbers that are integers but whose magnitudes are too great to store in an `int`.

Disclaimer 2: Doubles will hold the closest possible value that they can to any real number.  So this can only possibly return whether the *represented* digits form an integer.  Extremely large doubles, for example, are always integers because they don't have enough significant digits to represent any fractional value.

```
bool is_integer( double d )
{
    const int exponent_offset = 1023;
    const int mantissa_bits = 52;

    double_breakdown *db = &d;

    // See if exponent is too large to hold a decimal value.
    if ( db->exponent >= exponent_offset + mantissa_bits )
       return true;  // d can't represent non-integers

    // See if exponent is too small to hold a magnitude greater than 1.0.
    if ( db->exponent <= exponent_offset )
       return false; // d can't represent integers

    // Return whether any mantissa bits below the decimal point are set.
    return ( db->mantissa << db->exponent - exponent_offset == 0 );
}
```

Comment: I don't see that it's necessarily slower; `floor` and `(int)n` are masking a lot of complexity.

Comment: There is only one way to know for sure: compare assembly output. It's hard to beat compilers at micro-optimizations now.

Comment: the main cost of this code is the branches, which will only be costly if the branch predictor has trouble predicting.  other than that its 2 adds, 3 compares, and some masking implied by the the use of the bitfields.  In my experience, compilers do a better job optimizing explicit masks rather than bitfield stuff.  But this looks pretty fast to me.

Comment: Definatelay faster than floor() and int(). But perhaps could be speeded up with a couple of && and || bit comparisons on the rather than the >= which would require some bit shifting before the comparison could take place.

Comment: Time it and see if it is really faster. This is likely to incur a load-hit-store, which is much much slower than a call to floor().

Comment: Checkers: it's not as hard as you think -- I make my living at beating the compiler at its own game. Compilers are really not as smart as we assume.

Comment: @Crashworks: sometimes you can, sometimes you can't: that's why you look at the assembly and time it. http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf Note from paper on one of optimizations: "Note: gcc is smarter than the video codec programmer on all platforms."

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get hackish, see the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) spec.  Floating point numbers are implemented as a significand and an exponent.  I'm not sure exactly how to do it, but you could probably do something like:

```
union {
    float f;
    unsigned int i;
}
```

This would get you bitwise access to both the significand and exponent.  Then you could bit-twiddle your way around.

Comment: What's wrong with this?  He asked for a fast, but not necessarily portable way.

Comment: Un;ess the number is normalized, I'm not sure this will help a lot, to be honest.

Comment: This method does assume that the floating point is normalised. It probably would be, but it's still an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
inline int IsInteger(double n)
{
    double dummy;
    return modf(n, &dummy) == 0.0;
}
```